# I need all data in a model on a excel sheet Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a api,i which i want all data on a excel sheet

class Task(models.Model):

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
address=models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

#viewset

plan=Task.objects.all()

b=[]

for i in plan:

```
b.append({
    "name":i.name,
    "address":i.address,
    
})
```

return Response({"data":b})

output should be

0 name:address

1 Ashu:Gurgaon

Comment: You could write a method and place it into your views get method, so that it gets fired when you send a get request on that view. Within that method you can use `data = Task.objects.all()` to get all of your model data. Then you can use a library called openpyxl to open an excel file and with a simple for loop you could place the key and value into the sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643239/invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-name-django see this